# How to fix Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action error?

Tags: c++, api, websocket

**This is Binance cryptoexchange api. Im trying to get account informations but I could not do that. It's official C++ Api. [This is github link](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binacpp). This is error on terminal. When you answering the question, Please be easy. I am newbie**

2020-01-22 10:32:04 085219 :

2020-01-22 10:32:04 085245 : url = |https://api.binance.com/api/v1/userDataStream|

2020-01-22 10:32:04 085253 :

2020-01-22 10:32:04 698466 :

2020-01-22 10:32:04 698529 : done

2020-01-22 10:32:04 701234 : done

2020-01-22 10:32:04 701434 : Done.

2020-01-22 10:32:04 701472 : Done.

**{
    "code" : -2015,
    "msg" : "Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action."
}**

[2020/01/22 10:32:04:7018] NOTICE: libuv support not compiled in

[2020/01/22 10:32:04:7045] NOTICE: Creating Vhost 'default' port -1, 1 protocols, IPv6 off

[2020/01/22 10:32:04:7046] NOTICE: created client ssl context for default

[2020/01/22 10:32:04:7099] NOTICE: lws_client_connect_2: 0x239f3e0: address stream.binance.com

[2020/01/22 10:32:05:3128] NOTICE: lws_client_connect_2: 0x239f3e0: address stream.binance.com

**Here i entered my keys.**

```
 using namespace std;


#define API_KEY         "my api key here,deleted for security"
#define SECRET_KEY      "secret key is here, deleted for security"
```

and main function

```
int main() {

    Json::Value result;
    long recvWindow = 10000;    

    string api_key      = API_KEY;
    string secret_key   = SECRET_KEY;
    BinaCPP::init( api_key , secret_key );


    // User Balance
    BinaCPP::get_account( recvWindow , result );
    for ( int i  = 0 ; i < result["balances"].size() ; i++ ) {
        string symbol = result["balances"][i]["asset"].asString();
        userBalance[symbol]["f"] = atof( result["balances"][i]["free"].asString().c_str() );
        userBalance[symbol]["l"] = atof( result["balances"][i]["locked"].asString().c_str() );
    }
    print_userBalance();

    // User data stream 
    BinaCPP::start_userDataStream(result );
    cout << result << endl;

    string ws_path = string("/ws/");
    ws_path.append( result["listenKey"].asString() );



    BinaCPP_websocket::init();
    BinaCPP_websocket::connect_endpoint( ws_userStream_OnData , ws_path.c_str() ); 
    BinaCPP_websocket::enter_event_loop(); 


}
```

and this is a part of BinaCPP.cpp

```
#include "binacpp.h"
#include "binacpp_logger.h"
#include "binacpp_utils.h"




string BinaCPP::api_key = "my api key here";
string BinaCPP::secret_key = "secret key here";
CURL* BinaCPP::curl = NULL;




//---------------------------------
void 
BinaCPP::init( string &api_key, string &secret_key ) 
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    BinaCPP::curl = curl_easy_init();
    BinaCPP::api_key = api_key;
    BinaCPP::secret_key = secret_key;
}
```

Comment: Did you fill in `BinaCPP::api_key` with `API_KEY` as well? It is hard to tell.

Comment: @Botje Yes sir, I did.

Comment: Can you do the same action with, say, `curl` from the same IP? That rules out that your API key is invalid for the linked action/IP combination.

Comment: @Botje I guess found the reason but I am using official API and example. I understand nothing. https://pastebin.pl/view/f4e0e9cf

Comment: How can you simultaneously fail to compile the example and yet have it produce erorr messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this was the error I was running across in python.
If you set up your binance account with binance.us instead of binance.com you need to make sure that you change it in the scource files. In python it was as easy as passing the 'tld="us"' parameter when initializing the client class.

I saw that you had " url = |https://api.binance**.com**/api/v1/userDataStream|"
You may need " url = |https://api.binance**.us**/api/v1/userDataStream|"

Also, I noticed that your url had api/v1, just wanted to make sure that when you are grabbing account information or other requests that require your api_secret key it should roll over api/v2 or api/v3.

I am not familiar with C++ but here is a solution to perform a find/replace in python. Hope this information helps you!

You will need to navigate to the directory your github-downloaded files are located and try the following:

## check this code to make sure it is not replacing any .com's you may need.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.curdir):
    for f in files:
        file_name = os.path.join(root, f):
            try:
                with open(file_name, 'r') as fp:
                    data = fp.read().replace('.com', '.us')
                with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
                    fp.write(data)
            except:
                print(f.ljust(20), 'failed')
```

Comment: tld='us' worked for me. there are several places where american users have to double check to make sure they are connecting at the right points, like the url and which app they download.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had to log into the Binance [API Management page](https://www.binance.com/en/my/settings/api-management) and update my whitelisted IP addresses as I had since changed my Internet provider. Always worth checking!

Comment: I've listed over than 20 IPs as of now, and still the issue will come back often causing me to miss trades here and there. I wish that Binance API had more flexibility in dealing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to reactivate the trading permissions every 90 days. Make sure all the required boxes are ticked on the API management page (reading, spot/margin trading, etc.).