# Why do I get an error with node-binance-api?

Tags: javascript, binance

I try using node-binance-api. I've created a key - secretkey pair on binance.com, but I get  this error

```js
[Object: null prototype] {
  code: -2015,
  msg: 'Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action, request ip: *myip*'
}
```

Here is my code :

```js
const key='my key'
const secret='my secret'

const Binance = require('node-binance-api');
const binance = new Binance().options({
  APIKEY: key,
  APISECRET: secret
});

var f = async () => {
  var p = await binance.futuresAccount() 
  console.log(p)
}
f()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855006/how-to-fix-invalid-api-key-ip-or-permissions-for-action-error)

Comment: Most likely you did not whitelisted your IP